# Python - get list of all files from a folder (with more options)

Tags: python

Is exist some usual way to enumerate all files (and optionally folders, optionally recursive with sub dirs) inside a given folder? So I pass a folder path and get list of resulting full paths.

If you show how to exclude all read-only and all hidden files from this result, it'd be better. So input params:

- dir: full path of a folder
- option_dirs: include dirs paths to listing
- option_subdirs: process also all subdirs of dir
- option_no_ro: exclude read-only files
- option_no_hid: exclude hidden files

Python2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to list all files of a directory in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory-in-python)

Comment: Link shows answer for 1) and 2) options. But how to exclude RO and Hidden files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably look into [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) and [`os.access`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.access).

For the actual implementation you can do something like:

```
import os

def get_files(path, option_dirs, option_subdirs, option_no_ro, option_no_hid):
    outfiles = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        if option_no_hid:
            # In linux, hidden files start with .
            files = [ f for f in files if not f.startswith('.') ]
        if option_no_ro:
            # Use os.path.access to check if the file is readable
            # We have to use os.path.join(root, f) to get the full path
            files = [ f for f in files if os.access(os.path.join(root, f), os.R_OK) ]
        if option_dirs:
            # Use os.path.join again
            outfiles.extend([ os.path.join(root, f) for f in files ])
        else:
            outfiles.extend(files)
        if not option_subdirs:
            # If we don't want to get subdirs, then we just exit the first
            # time through the for loop
            return outfiles
    return outfiles
```

Comment: `import os.path` ; `option_no_ro` not used. Tks.

Comment: Whoops, fixed it so `option_no_ro` is used.